# Localization chooses wrong language based on accept-language header

Tags: asp.net-core, localization

I´am trying to add translations for some error messages, but I'am having a hard time figuring out some .net black magic.

Everything works in firefox, it seems to be because it sends the nb-No field in accept-language header.

Firefox header:
`nb-NO,nb;q=0.9,no-NO;q=0.8,no;q=0.6,nn-NO;q=0.5,nn;q=0.4,en-US;q=0.3,en;q=0.1`

but it doesn't work in chrome, this seems to be because it sends this accept-lanuage header:
`no,sv;q=0.9`

I have added support for both nb-NO and no (I thought). I have tried to add a file for each of the languages. This is how it looks:

[![Image of resx file layout in solution][1]][1]

So I have figured out that if the accept-language header is `no`it goes to Controllers.ErrorController.resx, why doesnt it go to Controllers.ErrorController.no.resx?

I'am using netcoreapp 2.1

I have added relevant code below:

So in startup it looks like this:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     ...
     services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources/Languages");
     services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(Language.ConfigureRequestLanguage());
     ...
}

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env,
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            ....
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/api/errors");
            app.UseRequestLocalization(Language.SupportedCultures());
            ...
}
```

The helper functions:

```
     public static class Language
        {
            private const string DefaultLanguage = "en-US";
            private static readonly CultureInfo[] SupportedUiCultures = {
                new CultureInfo(DefaultLanguage),
                new CultureInfo("no"),
                new CultureInfo("nb-NO"),
                new CultureInfo("sv"),
                new CultureInfo("sv-SE"),
            };
    
            public static Action<RequestLocalizationOptions> ConfigureRequestLanguage()
            {
                return options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: DefaultLanguage, uiCulture: DefaultLanguage);
                    options.SupportedCultures = SupportedUiCultures;
                    options.SupportedUICultures = SupportedUiCultures;
                    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(context =>
                    {
    
                        var userLanguages = context.Request.GetTypedHeaders().AcceptLanguage
                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Quality ?? 1);
    
                        var match = userLanguages.FirstOrDefault(r => SupportedUiCultures.Any(s => s.Name == r.Value.ToString()));
    
                        var prioritizedLanguage = match == null ? DefaultLanguage : match.Value.ToString();
                        var language = string.IsNullOrEmpty(prioritizedLanguage) ? DefaultLanguage : prioritizedLanguage;
                        return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(language, language));
                    }));
                };
            }
    
            public static RequestLocalizationOptions  SupportedCultures()
            {
                return new RequestLocalizationOptions
                {
                    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(DefaultLanguage),
                    SupportedCultures =  SupportedUiCultures,
                    SupportedUICultures = SupportedUiCultures
                };
            }
        }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W58R.png
```

Comment: `it doesn't work in chrome, this seems to be because it sends this accept-lanuage header: no,sv;q=0.9` What's the version of chrome? You can try to upgrade/downgrade the chrome and check if same issue occurs.

Comment: Sure I can upgrade, the problem is all the other users :).